# see where $_GET value is coming from - php

Tags: php

I have a question on how to know where this $_GET value come from

```
$book = isset($_GET['book']) ? $_GET['book'] : null;
```

The problem is that this site that i am working with, has too many pages and its hard to find it, im trying to solve an error dealing with the $_GET value but first I need to know where it is comming from.
Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: `$_GET` variable is coming from HTTP-GET query. So what does your question mean?

Comment: `$_GET` is a superglobal. It isn't coming from any code you're working with. It's coming from PHP itself. Either the URL has a query string with a parameter named "book" or it doesn't. (Someone may be adding values to the `$_GET` superglobal but that would be a very bad practice).

Comment: its like a <form> somewhere in the site, but i dont know where that is tho , there are too many pages!

Comment: The whole conditional statement is *a.k.a.* a ternary operator.

Comment: @KaylaJohnson It's relatively simple. If you have all the files on your computer, just search all files containing `$book = isset($_GET['book']) ? $_GET['book'] : null;` and you will find your form.

Comment: @Fred-ii- how can you do that in netbeans?

Comment: @KaylaJohnson I don't know Kayla, I never used Netbeans, but am sure there's probably some form of "search, or search & replace" option in there.

Answer (score 1):

Search the page manually and comment it in the php file it's the best way I could think off this is why you can comment out in languages its there and not for nothing...

Answer (score 0):

With $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] you will get the URL of the page that was opened before getting to your actual page. Use this to know where the people come from.

Comment: What happens if they were linked from https or clicked a link from an email or typed in the url themselves? `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` won't be available all the time.

Comment: I know, but I think in this case it will work. He can build in an if to be 100% sure and print an error if there is no ref feral...

Comment: @zerophreak - I think that he might be a she... I know I need glasses, but the OP's picture doesn't look very male to me... perhaps you should get out more :)